# How do I avoid import collisions when importing my own standard library?

Tags: rust

I am trying to import my own `std` library, but when I am compiling with crates dependencies I have this issue:

```
error: duplicate lang item in crate `std`: `f32`.
  |
  = note: first defined in crate `my_std`.

error: duplicate lang item in crate `std`: `f64`.
  |
  = note: first defined in crate `my_std`.

error: duplicate lang item in crate `std`: `panic_fmt`.
  |
  = note: first defined in crate `my_std`.
```

I tried to overwrite the library by writing `extern crate my_std as std`

What would be the easy way to fix that - and not modify this for all dependencies?

Comment: Why did you make your own `std` library?

Comment: Can you clarify "with crates dependencies"? Are you saying you want to compile other crates using your standard library, or that you want to compile your code with your standard library and other crates with the regular standard library, or something else?

Comment: I want to compile the code with my standard library `my_std`, including the dependencies (which may use std library).
@FrancisGagné: Because the std library might not be compatible within the environment I will be running the Rust binary (different sets of instructions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile your code without the Rust standard library by using [`#![no_std]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/using-rust-without-the-standard-library.html) attribute in your crate root. Note that there are some caveats to doing this with an executable (as opposed to a library), and you will need to [manually include libc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/lang-items.html#using-libc) for a binary.